# How to enable event clicking only on specific days columns fullCalendar v4

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to specify a config value for my system users allowing them to modify their working hours in current day and a specific number of previous days on a fullCalendar v4 Calendar.
Working hours ranges are clickable events.

Example :

- If config value is 3 that means the users will be able to modify the current day and two previous days.
- Modifying hours require clicking on an event.

Question : How to enable event clicking only on specific days columns ?

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar($('#agenda-calendar')[0], {
  columnHeaderFormat: {
    weekday: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    omitCommas: true
  },
  events: {
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
  },
  eventClick: function(info) {
    editEvent(info);
  },
  locale: '<?= Yii::app()->getLanguage() ?>',

  selectable: false,
  timeFormat: '',
  selectHelper: true,
  allDaySlot: false,
  plugins: ['timeGrid'],
  views: {
    timeGridMonthDay: {
      type: 'timeGrid',
      duration: {
        weeks: 1
      },
      buttonText: '<?=$this->_t( '
      Month ' )?>'
    }
  },
  defaultView: 'timeGridMonthDay',
  minTime: '7:00:00',
  maxTime: '22:00:00',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  }
});
```

Calendar Image

[image]

Comment: in the eventClick function, check the current date, and the date the user has clicked on (you can get this from the start date of the event, assuming you never have multi-day events). Compare the dates. If they are too far apart (as per the config value), don't run the editEvent function.